# how many inodes, open file table entries and file descriptors this program use

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I am reviewing some stuff for my job interview, on this question it asks at peak how many inodes, open file table entries and file descriptors this program use? Can you help me with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  char buffer[3] = "ab";
  int r = open("new.txt", O_RDONLY);
  int r1, r2, pid;
  r1 = dup(r);

  read(r, buffer, 1);

  if((pid=fork())==0) {
    r1 = open("new.txt", O_RDONLY);
  } else{
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
  }

  read(r1, buffer+1, 1);
  printf("%s", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When is `r2` used ?

Comment: Does the file "new.txt" exist? Is it accessible? What filesystem is this running on (not all filesystem have inodes)? What is a "file table entry", does it actually mean "file description" (which is not the same thing as "file descriptor") or is someone assuming a very particular operating system implementation? If that's the case, why isn't that part of the question? How are stdin/stdout/stderr set up?

How old is this question anyway? The terminology smells like written by someone who knew a few things about Unix in the 80s/early 90s.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  char buffer[3] = "ab";
  int r = open("new.txt", O_RDONLY);
  int r1, r2, pid;
  r1 = dup(r);

  read(r, buffer, 1);

  if((pid=fork())==0) {
    r1 = open("new.txt", O_RDONLY);
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }    
  } else{
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
  }

  read(r1, buffer+1, 1);
  printf("%s", buffer);

  return 0;
}

wutiejun@linux-00343520:~/Temp> gcc -o test main.c
wutiejun@linux-00343520:~/Temp> ./test &
[1] 10404
wutiejun@linux-00343520:~/Temp> ls -l /proc/10404/fd
Total 0
lrwx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 2 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 3 -> /home/wutiejun/Temp/new.txt
l-wx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 4 -> /home/wutiejun/Temp/new.txt
wutiejun@linux-00343520:~/Temp> ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
10404 pts/0    00:00:00 test
10405 pts/0    00:00:00 test
10417 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
wutiejun@linux-00343520:~/Temp> ls -l /proc/10405/fd
Total 0
lrwx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:34 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:34 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:34 3 -> /home/wutiejun/Temp/new.txt
lr-x------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:34 4 -> /home/wutiejun/Temp/new.txt
lr-x------ 1 wutiejun users 64  June  9 16:33 5 -> /home/wutiejun/Temp/new.txt
wutiejun@linux-00343520:~/Temp>
```

So, you can count the open files.
And I am not sure about the inode numbers, I think it depends on the different filesystems.

Answer (score 3):

We have to make a few assumptions here.

Assumption 1: We are running on a system where all filesystems use inodes (it's just a name of a data structure. Inodes have not been exposed as an abstraction to processes for decades). A perfectly valid answer for the "number of inodes" question could be: 0 because I'm running on NFS. I would be much more comfortable if the term used was "vnode" because even though it's also a system specific term it is actually more meaningful in many more systems than "inode".

Assumption 2: the program starts with stdin/stderr/stdout open and pointing to the same file description.

Assumption 3: stdin&co are a pty from /dev

Assumption 4: /dev is a normal directory, as in classic unix and not like linux where it's a devfs. Also, the pty was opened as a normal file just like in the early 90s, not through some kind of cloning mechanism.

Assumption 5: "new.txt" exists and is accessible to this process.

Assumption 6: "file table entry" actually means [file description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_258).

Assumption 7: the program is not dynamically linked. This is because a dynamic linker could have opened an arbitrarily large number of files before the program reached `main`.

Assumption 8: stdio in libc doesn't open various locale and such databases until they are actually needed.

Assumption 9: things that can fail (`fork`, `open`, `dup`), don't.

Assumption 10: `pid_t` fits in an `int`.

Let's see what happens (the skipped lines are irrelevant to the question).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
```

At this point we have three open file descriptors. As in the assumptions, those file descriptors point to the same file description which comes from the same file on the filesystem.

Score (descriptors, descriptions, inodes): 3, 1, 1

```
int r = open("new.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

We successfully open a file.

Score: 4, 2, 2

```
r1 = dup(r);
```

We successfully dup the file descriptor. A `dup`:d file descriptor points to the same file description as the original descriptor.

Score: 5, 2, 2

```
if((pid=fork())==0) {
```

Fork copies the file descriptor table, but the descriptors still point to the same descriptions.

Score: 10, 2, 2

```
r1 = open("new.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

This creates a new file description that points to the same inode as we've already opened.

Score: 11, 3, 2

```
} else {
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

Let's assume that the child process has successfully exited despite doing it in a quite unclean way (`fork`ed children should exit through `_exit`, not by returning from `main`, but we'll let it slide this time). The child process closes all its descriptors, this also causes one description to be closed because it only had one reference.

Score: 5, 2, 2

Answer: Given all the assumptions, the peak was 11 file descriptors, 3 file descriptions ("file table entries" if we insist on using archaic terminology), 2 inodes.

Alternative answer: 11, 2 + X, 1 + Y, where X is the number of descriptions that stdin/out/err use and Y is the same for number of inodes.